# VBA Vlookup slow and crashing

Tags: excel, vba, performance, vlookup

My VBA vlookup code is crashing excel, and takes forever to execute even though the file size is 519 KB. I tried to switch it to a Index/Match, and still takes forever. Other modules work perfectly with no hussle. I need the vba and not the formula in cell because i use the content of the vlookup cells in later countifs

```
Public Sub MatchRC()
    Dim DCP_nbr As String
    Dim Rootcause As String
    Dim xrange As Range
    Dim trange As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim hrange As Range
    Dim here As String
    Dim c As Range


    lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'trange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J:K")

    For x = 2 To lastRow
     On Error Resume Next

         If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then
             'xrange = Range("x,B")
             DCP_nbr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value
             here = Application.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DCP_nbr, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:K2000"), 2, False), "Error")
             'Range("x,G").Value = here
             ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 7).Value = here
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 7).Value = "Error"
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd build a lookup table. Take a look at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203421/index-match-implementation) over on CR for the basic gist.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Whatever` will throw a VBA run-time error if the function means to *return* an error. Use the late-bound `Application.Whatever` instead (e.g. `Application.VLookup`), then remove `On Error Resume Next`, which may be hiding other errors. `Application.IfError` isn't picking up the errors `VLookup` is throwing, because it's *throwing* them, rather than *returning* them.

Comment: A for performance, you're comparing apples to oranges - VBA code shouldn't need to loop across cells like this, it's slow by definition. That said "I need the vba and not the formula in cell because i use the content of the vlookup cells in later countifs", sounds very much like your later countifs could be in-cell formulas too??

Comment: You're also dereferencing the worksheet off `ActiveWorkbook` *every single time* you want to access a cell. If `Sheet1` exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, use its code name and do `Sheet1.Cells(x, 2).Value` instead - the sheet is *already* referenced by a global-scope object by that name (see its `(Name)` property). That said pulling your lookup range/results into a dictionary and then using it as a lookup table would be much faster. Populate a 2D variant array as you go, then make one single worksheet write by dumping the 2D array where it needs to be.

Comment: Sorry, by slow I mean that every time i try to run the code it takes more than 20 min to work. I doubt it's normal. My later countifs are incell formulas, it's the outcome i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this instead?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws.Range("G2:G" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        .Formula = "=IF(B" & .Row & "<>"""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B" & .Row & ",$J:$K,2,FALSE),""Error""),""Error"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OP's stated _"I need the vba and not the formula in cell..."_

Comment: @DisplayName You're correct, that's why the `.Value = .Value` line converts the formulas to their values

Comment: @DisplayName to be fair, I still have no idea why the heck OP needs any VBA for this.

Answer (score 0):

summing up some of pieces of advice given in comments:

```
Public Sub MatchRC()
    Dim DCP_nbr As String

    Dim c As Range
    Dim res As Variant, lookUpVals As Variant, retVals As Variant

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' reference your sheet once and for all
        lookUpVals = .Range("J2:J2000").Value ' fill lookup array with referenced sheet range J2:J2000
        retVals = .Range("K2:K2000").Value 'fill return values array with referenced sheet range K2:K2000


        With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column B cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            For Each c In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced range not empty values (assuming there will alwyas be at least two ...)
                 DCP_nbr = c.Value ' get current not empty value
                 res = Application.Match(DCP_nbr, lookUpVals) ' try searching current value in lookup array
                 If IsError(res) Then ' if not found
                    c.Offset(, 5) = "Error"
                 Else
                    c.Offset(, 5) = retVals(res, 1) ' write corresponding return values array item
                 End If
            Next
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, 5) = "Error" ' place "Error" in column "G" cells corresponding to column "B" empty ones
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```